# Can I pair 2 Bluetooth headsets to my iPad simultaneously? We watch tv on it when traveling

Tags: ipad, bluetooth, headphones

We own 2 pairs of the same headsets and wish to pair them simultaneously to watch tv on the iPad.  Only one at a time seems to work.  They have the same name which may be the issue, but I can't find an answer online.

Is it possible to send audio to two Bluetooth headsets simultaneously? If so, how?

Answer (score 5):

iOS will only output sound to one device at a time, and that includes the internal speakers. So no, you can't pair multiple Bluetooth headsets and listen through both simultaneously.

Your only options would be to:

1. Each use a single earpiece from the same headset.
2. Purchase a [Bluetooth splitter](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B01B4W40VC).

Comment: FYI earphone splitters work a treat, used them myself from time to time.

Comment: @SteveChambers Agreed. I've used splitters for the kids on long car trips more times than I can remember.

Comment: The new iPads don't have jack outputs anymore, so headphone splitters don't work. The Bose+ app works great for me for connecting two Bose headphones through bluetooth.